# Resize height of php function image - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, pdf

Hi I'm a bit of a newbie to php. Currently I'm working on a custom pdf invoice but trying to use one image in two different places but need them to be two sizes at the moment my first placing fits well but the other placing needs to be smaller. I'm a little lost in how to achieve this.

```html
<td class="logo-label">
   <table>
    <td class="header">
  <?php
  if( $this->has_header_logo() ) {
   $this->header_logo();
  } else {
   echo $this->get_title(); {
  }
  ?>
```

The idea height would be 28px (pixels) from the original 48px. I've tried everything but cannot seem to get it to work without it breaking the pdf. 
[Image of what it looks like in pdf form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWqEa.jpg)

Comment: I recommend getting a library like [fPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and creating an actual PDF, because what you have up there is HTML.

Comment: You can use dompdf its also a great library to generate the pdf files